# Autocomplete With Tags in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, autocomplete, sonata-admin

I want to implement autocomplete with tags in sonata admin bundle. You can see the demo 
http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-wieth-tags.html.

Can autocomplete functionality is exist in GenemuFormbundle select2??
if it is exists how to implement in sonata admin bundle and if not, then suggest me some more bundle or source code or a tutorial.

Comment: BTW there is a typo in your link. Correct version should be: http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-tags.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sonata_type_model_autocomplete` type. It is native form type available in SonataAdmin in master branch (is part of SonataAdmin 2.3 release).
It is prepared to be used in many-to-one or many-to-many relations to help work with too many items.

Documentation: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/form_types.rst#sonata_type_model_autocomplete

Example: create autocomplete field in `ArcticleAdmin` on `category` field.

```php
class ArticleAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        // the dropdown autocomplete list will show only Category entities that contains specified text in "title" attribute
        $formMapper
            ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete', array('property'=>'title'))
        ;
    }
}

class CategoryAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        // this text filter will be used to retrieve autocomplete fields
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('title')
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some time sonata admin bundle integrates directly compatibility with select2.

See http://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/1/admin-bundle-select2-integration.

I would recommend using this method rather than rely to a bundle outside!